# How to identify pairs in a string

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have the string : `"((a,(b,c)),(d,(e,(f,g))))"`

How would I go about extracting each pair separately such as splitting the first pair and extracting `(a,(b,c))` and `(d,(e,(f,g)))`.

I am kind of lost as to how I should approach this. Since the pairs can vary as the example I can't exactly look for a set pattern.

I believe an approach to this would be identifying where the `","` is in the outer most parentheses. such as finding it in `( (set of pairs 1) , (set of pairs 2))`.
so I can then be able to take everything left of it and right of it. But I do not know how to do this. Using `str.Indexof()` will take the first occurrence of `","` which is not the one I am interested in.

Comment: Will valid input always be *only* pairs, or could there be `( (set of pairs 1) , (set of pairs 2) , (set of pairs 3) )`? And do you need to allow for invalid input not following that pattern?

Comment: no it is always a pair, it could be ( (set 1), ()) but it cannot be more then 2

Comment: Scan a character at a time and count parentheses as you go.

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through the string's characters keeping track of how nested the parentheses are, to find the first comma that isn't nested, and then (as you said) take the parts to the left and right of that:

```js
function getPairs(input) {
  // remove outer parentheses, if present
  if (input[0] === "(")
    input = input.slice(1,-1);
  // find first comma that isn't inside parentheses
  var parenNestLevel = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (parenNestLevel === 0 && input[i] === ",")
      return [input.slice(0, i), input.slice(i+1)];
    else if (input[i] === "(")
      parenNestLevel++;
    else if (input[i] === ")")
      parenNestLevel--;
  }
  // note: returns undefined if the input couldn't be parsed
}

var input = "((a,(b,c)),(d,(e,(f,g))))";
var pairs = getPairs(input);
console.log(pairs);
console.log(getPairs(pairs[0]));
```

For your input, that would return the array `["(a,(b,c))", "(d,(e,(f,g)))"]`, and you could then run `getPairs()` on the parts of the returned array, or make it recursive, or whatever - you don't really make it clear what the *final* output should be from your sample `"((a,(b,c)),(d,(e,(f,g))))"` input.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler solution. We first remove the first and last parenthesis, then split the resulting string with '),(', then iterate over the result and prepend/append the missing parenthesis to individual elements depending on their position:

```
var a = "((a,(b,c)),(d,(e,(f,g))))";
var b = a.substring(1,a.length-1); //remove first and last parenthesis
var c = b.split('),('); //get pairs
for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++){
  if(i%2===0){
    c[i] = c[i]+')';
  }else{
    c[i] = '('+c[i];
  }
}
console.log(c); // ["(a,(b,c))", "(d,(e,(f,g)))"]
```

Comment: What if the input is `"(a,(b,c))"`? (E.g., if trying to further split up the pairs returned from the initial operation.) There's still a pair (the second part of which is itself another pair), but there's no `"),("` to split on...